# several geom in one row in cartodb

Tags: geometry, cartodb

Is it possible to have several geom columns in cartodb? So I want to have something like this:

geom_city1 | name_city1 | geom_city2 | name_city2

So all geoms are supposed to be points.
How do I add the second geom column to my dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  One row in the table represents one object - your example suggests two objects with two separate geometries.  If you have two cities (as per your example), those should be two separate rows, not one row with multiple geometry columns.